# Declared Exception still throwing error must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, exception

First of all, I'm not a Java programmer and I'm just modifying existing code to suit my needs so please bear with me because of my very limited knowledge in Java.

This is a part of my code:

```
public String getIp() throws Exception {
    URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                whatismyip.openStream()));
        String ip = in.readLine();
        return ip;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I try to call `getIp()`, I'm having a compilation failure: `unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown`.

Here's part of the code that calls the `getIp()`:

```
Phrase downloadDate = new Phrase();
downloadDate.add(new Chunk("On: " + new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy").format(new Date()), FONT_DATE));
downloadDate.add(new Chunk(" at " + new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a z").format(new Date()), FONT_DATE));
Phrase downloader = new Phrase("This article was downloaded by: " + getEperson(), FONT_DATE);
String IP = getIp();
Phrase userIP = new Phrase("IP Address: " + IP, FONT_DATE);
Phrase userDownloadDate = new Phrase(downloadDate);
Paragraph downloadDetails = new Paragraph();
downloadDetails.add(downloader);
downloadDetails.add(downloadDate);
downloadDetails.add(userIP);
```

This may be a trivial question to ask, but I'm wondering why I'm having the error "must be caught or declared to be thrown" when it is already declared in the `public String getIp()`?

Comment: Since it's not mentioned currently: These are called [_checked exceptions_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getIp() method signature is:

```
public String getIp() throws Exception {
```

which means that there is a chance this function could throw an exception. The throws clause is used to specify all kinds of exception the function could throw.

When you call this method, you must specifically handle all the exceptions that could be possible. Like:

```
try {
    String ip = getIp();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // getIp() failed
}
```

Or since you have used a try block in getIp() method, if you are sure that it does not throw any exception, then you can just remove the throws clause like:

```
public String getIp() {
```

and your code should work.

And an offside note: the getIp() method does not return a string in all cases. Just add a `return "";` at the end of its definition to avoid runtime issues.

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that the calling function must catch or declare to be thrown. Once an exception is explicitly declared on a method signature, all calling functions have to deal with that exception int the way mentioned in the error message.